# Unclear points on feature extraction for a set of scenarios

Tags: machine-learning, pattern-recognition, feature-extraction

The following is an example from a book (An Introduction to Pattern
Recognition and Machine Learning by P. Fieguth, page 85) on feature extraction and selection.
Please consider the following figure.

[image]

I have the following questions:

Q1- Why in Scenario IV will the applicable distance metric in 3D be "very non-Euclidean"? The points in Scenario IV are also in a 3D space for which an Euclidian distance metric is valid in my opinion.

Q2-Why will feature projection to 2D be linear for Scenario 1?

Q3- Why is there only one meaningful feature direction for Scenario 1?

Comment: Please, one question per post.